# How to convert an array element to simplae element in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

My question may sound somewhat clumsy but that is what I wanted to do.
I'm having an array named `$data` obtained from SQL query. For your reference I'm putting here it's first two elements:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 9f27643023a83addd5eed41c4aade840
            [test_pack_name] => Bank Exams Complete Combo
            [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains 24 tests of Reasoning, English and Quantitative Aptitude + 2 Mega tests of all 3 subjects.

Total Tests in this Package : 26
            [test_pack_type_id] => 3
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 3
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => paid
            [test_pack_price] => 399.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_sold] => 1
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => 81c4e3607c7e56bbf5461ef150437675
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1347127051
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1349235701
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 1351228594
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => e7e95de96987cc7c89c1f0183110fb38
            [test_pack_name] => Bank Reasoning
            [test_pack_desc] => This package contains 8 tests on Reasoning.
            [test_pack_type_id] => 3
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 3
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => free
            [test_pack_price] => 0.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_sold] => 4
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1347127196
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1347127387
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 1363775709
        )
)
```

Now I've to insert one new key-value pair in this array. For it I'm firing one query onto the database. The query will be fired for each and every element of array `$data`. The code for it is as below:

```
foreach($data as $data1) {  

            $sql  = " SELECT COUNT(*) as package_count FROM ". TBL_USER_PACKAGES. " WHERE pack_id ='".$data1['test_pack_id']."' AND pack_assign_date  ";  
            $sql .= " BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day)) ";
            $this->mDb->Query( $sql);
            $data1['package_sold_count'] = $this->mDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);
}
```

But when I access the result of this query, I'm getting it in array format like this :

```
Array(
[0] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 9f27643023a83addd5eed41c4aade840
            [test_pack_name] => Bank Exams Complete Combo
            [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains 24 tests of Reasoning, English and Quantitative Aptitude + 2 Mega tests of all 3 subjects.

Total Tests in this Package : 26
            [test_pack_type_id] => 3
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 3
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => paid
            [test_pack_price] => 399.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_sold] => 1
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => 81c4e3607c7e56bbf5461ef150437675
            [test_pack_created_date] => 303
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1349235701
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 256
            [package_sold_count] => Array
                (
                    [package_count] => 4
                )
[1] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => e7e95de96987cc7c89c1f0183110fb38
            [test_pack_name] => Bank Reasoning
            [test_pack_desc] => This package contains 8 tests on Reasoning.
            [test_pack_type_id] => 3
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 3
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => free
            [test_pack_price] => 0.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_sold] => 4
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 303
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1347127387
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 110
            [package_sold_count] => Array
                (
                    [package_count] => 2
                )
)
```

Actually I wanted the array as a new key-value pair instead of a new associative array as follows :

```
    Array(
    [0] => Array
            (
                [test_pack_id] => 9f27643023a83addd5eed41c4aade840
                [test_pack_name] => Bank Exams Complete Combo
                [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains 24 tests of Reasoning, English and Quantitative Aptitude + 2 Mega tests of all 3 subjects.

    Total Tests in this Package : 26
                [test_pack_type_id] => 3
                [test_pack_image] => 
                [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
                [test_pack_validity_month] => 3
                [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
                [test_pack_plan] => paid
                [test_pack_price] => 399.00
                [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
                [test_pack_publish] => yes
                [test_pack_sold] => 1
                [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
                [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => 81c4e3607c7e56bbf5461ef150437675
                [test_pack_created_date] => 303
                [test_pack_updated_date] => 1349235701
                [test_pack_purchase_date] => 256
                [package_sold_count] => 4

)
```

Can anyone help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as the following should work fine, to do what you want:

```
<?php
    foreach ($array as &$subArray) {
        $subArray["package_sold_count"] = $subArray["package_sold_count"]["package_count"];
    }
    unset($subArray);
?>
```

or simply set it differently when you assign it:

```
foreach($data as $data1) {  

            $sql  = " SELECT COUNT(*) as package_count FROM ". TBL_USER_PACKAGES. " WHERE pack_id ='".$data1['test_pack_id']."' AND pack_assign_date  ";  
            $sql .= " BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day)) ";
            $this->mDb->Query( $sql);

            //First assign a variable
            $dbFetch = $this->mDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE); 

            //Then refer to it
            $data1['package_sold_count'] = $dbFetch["package_count"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch your new key/value pair in this line:

```
 $data1['package_sold_count'] = $this->mDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);
```

you're actually fetching an array, even if it's only one element, so that's what you see.

Instead, do this:

```
$temp = $this->mDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);
$data1['package_sold_count'] = $temp['package_count']; // assumes associative array
```

This might work too, but I've occasionally had trouble packing code up too tightly.

```
$data1['package_sold_count'] = $this->mDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE)['package_count'];
```